# Change property to read only is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I've a table with inline create i.e. you click on add row and it opens an editable row
which you can put data in and have a save button.

What I try to do is two things

1. when you click on save *(btnsubmit)*  it changes the row status from `editable` to `read only`. How should I do that?
2. And add a new button for editing to this specific row..

This is the code I want, the text box name and check box 1 will be changed to read only

```
//Append new row
var html = '<tr><td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td><td><input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td><td></tr>';

function addRow() {
    if ($('#btnsubmit').length == 0) {

        jQuery(html).prependTo('#data-table');
       
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
        
            $('#btnsubmit').hide();
            $('#name').prop('readonly', true);
            initRowEvents(jQuery(document));

        });
      
    }
}
```

the name property was not changed to read only...
I tried with `hide` to the row button, but I'mm not sure if its the best way since when I do `remove` the action is not invoked...

Comment: I think you're looking for the attr() method instead of prop(). That seems to do what you want.

Comment: fyi, prop("readonly", true) works in Microsoft Edge at least, but it's kind of irrelevant.  So what's that say about Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmab8/

everything You do right, except it's not a prop, but attr :-)

```
$('input').attr('readonly','')
```

Comment: Thanks but how should I omit the text box rectangle ?voted up!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tmab8/1/ .prop() works too. Actually, I haved some problems with .attr() in Firefox, and .prop() solved it.

Comment: Jean, what do You mean by omitting rectangle? Is it the thing: http://jsfiddle.net/tmab8/2/ ?
@Miljan, attr not working in FF? Could You please make a non working fiddle? I gotta check it

Comment: Correct Entio ,where should I put the input none that just when I click on the create and the field turn to read-only  the border will be removed..

Comment: @entio I can't reproduce problem now, but it occured when I was working on selecting option from select menu based on page id. Customer was frustrated, and solution was to use .prop() function. Or maybe that was the problem with mobile browsers because site was responsive... I can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

readonly is not a prop rather an attribute as per HTML specifications at [Readonly W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Trying this would work:

```
$('#name').attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `$('#name').attr('readonly', true);`

Comment: Then you have to post your html code so i can help you cause this one works for sure :)

Comment: sorry its working  but how should I omit the text box rectangle ?voted up!

Comment: You mean to remove border from textbox?

Comment: Then in your css you can use #name{border:none;} or if you want in js then you can use $('#name').css("border","none"). Hope that helps :)